# How to structure publish() and process() in a SwingWorker to update more than one Swing component on the EDT?

Tags: java, multithreading, swingworker

I have a ServerSocketChannel connection process in a SwingWorker. In the Swing application itself, two JLabels should update with (1) a String (connection status) and (2) an int (# of clients connected). Below is a screenshot of the application before "Detect Clients" JButton runs the connection process. However, I am not sure how to publish() and process() so as to update more than one Swing component on the EDT. Does anyone have guidance on how to achieve this?

[image: ScreenShot]

Because `List<V>` is the parameter of process(), I tried `<Object>` as `<V>`. However, this seems to run into issues of conversion from Strings/ints to Objects, and then vice versa.

The below demo code illustrates several points where updates should be published:

```
protected Void doInBackground() {
    try {
       // Omitted: obtain selector
       ServerSocketChannel ssc = ServerSocketChannel.open() // could fail, may need
       // to publish status
       ssc.socket().bind(serverAddress); // could fail, may need to publish status
       ssc.configureBlocking(false); // could fail, may need to publish status
       // Omitted: register ssc
       while (true) {
           int count = sel.select(1000); // may need to publish for # of clients
           // Omitted: rest of processing     
       }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //handle error
    } 
}
```

Comment: did you try following the examples from the SwingWorker javadoc?  it's pretty straightforward.  the example updates one component in the `process()` method, but it should be pretty straight forward to update multiple components.

Comment: @jtahlborn I did adopt the examples from the javadoc. I kept running into issues with conversion and errors indicating my process() did not override the superclass version. It was getting confusing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, now i understand your problem.  you are trying to publish 2 different bits of information.  note that the List passed into the `process()` method could contain the results of *multiple* `publish()` calls, so passing different types of values will get confused in your `process()` method.  instead, you should create a simple object to encapsulate *all* of the state you wish to pass, and always publish instances of that class (which will also solve all of your casting issues).  e.g.:

```
public class ChannelStatus {
  public final boolean active;
  public final int numClients;
}
```

Then, you would always publish a ChannelStatus instance with the current number of clients and "active" status.

Comment: He can differentiate between int and String easily as I described, however this would be my preferred method, too. One other thing he could do, is to set the progress (int flag) and listen for the "progress" bound property. Then he could differentiate between String and an int in registered PropertyChangeListener, based on that flag.

Comment: @iccthedral - what if one of the "string" values happens to parse as an "int"?  shoving a bunch of heterogeneous data into string values and hoping for the best on the other end is...  dubious at best.

Comment: My thanks. Your solution results in clearer and simpler code to handle various states. I also incorporated iccthedral's propertychange listener solution, so humming along very nicely now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use String as a result type. Say, for an integer (num of clients) do `publish(String.valueOf(integer))`,  And then in your `process()` method try something like

```
try {
 int numClients = Integer.parseInt(passedString);
 //all well, it's the client number
} catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
 //not a number, must be a connection status
}
```

Or simply wrap the two information in a separate class with `setNumClients, setConnStatus` and appropriate getters, populate it as you progress, and publish the object of that class.

Do tell me if I haven't understood you properly because I have a hunch you might want `PropertyChangeListeners` involved here.

Comment: I think your understanding of my problem is correct. I will try again in a few hours using your proposed structure. It will be frustrating if the @Override annotation error I mentioned above crops up again.

Comment: PropertyChangeListeners might be the ticket. I'll research those and SwingWorkers and let you know how it goes. Thank you for your time.

Comment: All well. If you need further help, just let me know.